# Contact YouTube

Tags: password, youtube, contact-page

Is there any direct way do contact a „real” person, an YouTube employer?

Someone created an account for the company I work for (previous employer). She entered some password and e-mail. The provided e-mail was valid, but since last login (more than two years), we changed our domain, and this e-mail is probably not valid anymore (and we even don't know it), co we can't use option to reset password.

I have used all the options in YouTube help center, and no one worked. Also we *can't* contact this previous employer to get any data she entered in the registration form.

The only data I know is the username. All the movies present the products of our company,
there are links to our site in movie descriptions, so there should be no problem to prove that the account is ours.

This is an urgent case, becouse the movies contain outdated information.

Comment: Is the previous domain still active?

Comment: @Piers The previous domain is now used by some other company.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this would work for you, but I was able to reclaim a YouTube account utilizing the Copyright and Trademark section of their website.  If you can prove that the trademark belongs to you and that the account utilizes the trademark, they may be able to transfer the account.